# Vue test utils not detecting Bootstrap component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test a component that uses a child component `WarnOnUnsavedModal`. I'm not trying to test the child component, however.

The child component uses `<b-modal>`, and in node_modules, that imports a component called `bBtn`.

When I try to run my test file, it fails with the following message:

```
import bBtn from '../button/button';
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

My test file:

```
import BootstrapVue, { bBtn } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import ComponentName from '../ComponentName.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('ComponentName', () => {
    it('Has props', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(ComponentName, {
            store,
            createLocalVue,
            stubs: {
                ModalWarnOnSave,
                'b-btn': bBtn,
            },
            propsData: {
                resourceType: 'General',
            },
        });

        expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

I've tried adding a line like this to the stubs:

```
stubs: {
    ModalWarnOnSave: true,
},
```

Why isn't that component being picked up here? I've tried swapping out `localVue.use()` with `Vue.use()`, to no avail.

What do I need to do to get this test to run? I'm happy to ignore the child file that's causing the problem.

Comment: Are you importing `ModalWarnOnSave`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
import BootstrapVue, { BButton } from 'bootstrap-vue'
```

`bBtn` is not the exported name of the `b-button` component. `b-btn` is an alias component name when Vue.use'ing BootstrapVue.

See https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button#importing-individual-components

Comment: Where do I then use BButton? I tried adding it to stubs in various ways such as `{BButton}`, `"b-button": BButton"` etc but the same error appears

Comment: Is there an reason you are stubbing b-button?

Comment: If I import it without using it in the file the Linter shouts at me. And it wasn't working without stubbing so I thought I'd try it with stubbing to see if it made a difference but it didn't unfortunately

Comment: Without knowing the structure of `ComponentName.vue` and how you are importing/using `b-button`, it is hard to help.